# Save output of a Mongo Command to a Variable bash script

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4, bash

I have been writing a script to find and kill slow mongodb queries, how can I store output of db.currentOp() in a variable?

current I am using this but failing

```
#! /bin/bash

out=""
mongo << EOF

out=db.currentOp();
EOF
echo"----------------------------"
echo"$out"
```

Updated Script

```
#! /bin/bash

out=$(mongo --eval 'db.currentOp({op:"query"})')
echo"-----------------------"
echo"$out"
```

Output

```
./kill_slow_mongo_queries.sh: line 4: echo-----------------------: command not found
./kill_slow_mongo_queries.sh: line 5: echoMongoDB shell version v3.6.8
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("ce96f3ee-f5e1-49b5-aeef-b5766328dda3") }
MongoDB server version: 3.6.8
{ "inprog" : [ ], "ok" : 1 }: No such file or directory
```

Comment: simply `out=$( echo "db.currentOp()" | mongo )` ?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit
i did try this and I was able to save the output in variable but it says
`bye: No such file or directory` in the end of the output, couldn't figure out why it was saying "No such file or directory" so I thought I was doing something wrong

Comment: Can you show your full script/command

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Added updated script and output to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mongo -command have multiple parameters that are handy in this case.

'--eval' let you run commands and '--quiet' keep all clutter away

```
out=$(mongo --quiet --eval="db.currentOp()") ; echo $out
```

Comment: you should must add always some text so that ithers can use it or adapt it, you just triggert the low qualtity review

Comment: why doesn't it work when i put

 ```out=$(mongo --quiet --eval="db.currentOp({op:"query"})") ;
echo $out```


i get output



```2021-03-16T10:37:14.575+0530 E QUERY [thread1] ReferenceError: query is not defined : @(shell eval):1:15
2021-03-16T10:37:14.575+0530
E
QUERY
[thread1]
ReferenceError:
query
is
not
defined
:
@(shell
eval):1:15
```

Comment: @DBguy  change "query" to 'query'... Because first "-character terminates string what started after eval=" OR use out=$(mongo --quiet --eval="db.currentOp({op:\"query\"})") ; echo $out

Comment: @JJussi thatnks it worked